# Ionic 4 : Setting root page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In Ionic 4 I couldn't find a suitable way to replace the default root page after the splash screen. Following is the default setup.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution. First create the page you want to make as root page

```
 ionic generate page pagename
```

In app.component.ts

```
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Inside the constructor add

```
 private router : Router
```

and then initialize

```
 initializeApp() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('pagename');
       this.statusBar.styleDefault();
       this.splashScreen.hide();
     });
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but i am facing issue. I have login and home page. On login page, once user login, i save session to localstorage and as per your answer, i tried to check condition on app.component.ts and navigate to home directly. It works, but sometimes, it shows login page for a second and then it redirects me to home page. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Try to do something like this : first call localstorage for session. if you got any and is valid navigate to home page else go to login page.

Comment: Works for me. In Ionic 4.

Comment: This is not setting the root, but only navigate to page.

Answer (score 7):

I would not suggest using this method.

although this works, Ionic 4 now relies on Native Angular Modules, this includes the Angular Router.

to set a root page, you would be required to set your app routes in the router module.

if you do not know how this is done, [please click here to visit the angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

when you create a project with the ionic cli, the routing module is added for you automatically.

Here is how to implement such in your case;

step 1:

*in your index.html*

check if the `<base href="/" >` has been added to the index.html file, if it's not there please add it.

step2:

*in your app.module.ts file*

at the top of the file, import the routerModule

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

configure your app routes, assuming you have already created a page named 'home'

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
redirectTo: 'home',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
path: 'home',
loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
}
];
```

add the RouterModule to the imports array of the NgModule

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
...
})
```

step 3:

*in your app.component.html*

add the router-outlet to the app.component.html
`<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>`

Comment: What is `main` for on `ion-router-outlet`?

Comment: sorry the main was a custom directive. i have removed it since it is not required for ionic navigation @trebor

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Angular Router this is the procedure:

in app.component:

Add imports:

```
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

// in the constructor:

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private navController: NavController,
...

  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
....
    if ( this.route.snapshot['_routerState'].url !== '/theRoute') {
         this.navController.navigateRoot('/theRoute')
           .then();
    }
....
```

Thats all.

This valid your logic and redirect, but, if You are in the same page, dont redirect.

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 3 we had push, pop & setRoot methods in NavController for Routing used as follows:

```
this.navCtrl.push('list');
this.navCtrl.pop('home');
this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
```

These are now changed to

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/list');
this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/home');
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/details');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Given below

**1.For Rooting:**

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  rootPage: any = 'register'; //<--- Just change the 'register' into your page name
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router : Router
  ) {

    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

}
```

**2. For Navigating:**

For just navigating to another page, use below code

```
initializeApp() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('Your_page_name');
       this.statusBar.styleDefault();
       this.splashScreen.hide();
     });
```